# Mongoose search for lower and upper case letters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have in my database the field "City". The field is entered by the user. How can I search with collection.find for upper and lower case independently?
So that B`usiness.find({ city : city }` displays "Berlin" and "berlin" as result?

Or I need to create two request to the database, with search for upper and anotherone for lower case?

I have the latest Mongoose and NodeJS Version.

**Solved**
found in mongoDB docs the following code which works for me

```
Business.find({ city : { $regex: city, $options: 'i' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

Found in MongoDB docs the following which works for me

```
Business.find({ city : { $regex: city, $options: 'i' } }
```